# Add extra text next to Select2 multi selected data

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-select2

I am choosing Select2 multi. The products I selected have a price and I want people to see it. But I want to get this (data-price = "5.00") out of here. How can I add this?

So exactly what I want to do;

[image: So exactly what I want to do;]

The shape that appears to me;

[image: The shape that appears to me;]

- Özellik 1 (5)
- Özellik 1 (1)

```html
<select multiple="" data-placeholder="Ekstra Malzeme Seçin.." class="ekstra form-control" name="coklu[]" data-select2-id="1" tabindex="-1" aria-hidden="true">
        <option value="Özellik 1" data-price="5" data-select2-id="12">Özellik 1 </option>
        <option value="Özellik 2" data-price="1" data-select2-id="13">Özellik 2 </option>
</select>
```

```js
$('.ekstra').select2();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the option `templateSelection` to pass a custom renderer. The given parameter `state` holds the text (`state.text`) and the specified data attributes (`state.element.dataset ('price')`)

```
$('.ekstra').select2({
    templateSelection: function (state) {
        return $(
            '<span>' + state.text + ' ' + state.element.dataset['price'] + ' TL</span>'
        );
    }
});
```

For more options see https://select2.org/configuration/options-api

Comment: You are great :)